# Canon printer Pixma IX6810 Service Mode?

Tags: printer, services, mode

I've been looking everywhere but still no luck. I own this printer Canon Pixma IX6810 (A3+ size printing), I need to enter service mode but can't find a way to do so. Service mode takes place using specific series of button presses on the printer, then special software is used to access special configurations on the printer. I've been able to do this on several Canon printers that I have owned, but not for the IX6810. It's not a common printer, it seems it was mostly sold on South America.

- I don't know what's the max printing pages limit for this printer. Some printer models will stop working once you get there and demand to be taken to service in order to continue printing.
- Besides the page print limit there is the waste ink pad limit, a calculation made by the printer on how much supposed ink is on the waste pad prior ink bleeding, once you get there, the printers will lock up and refuse printing, demanding to be taken to service in order to continue printing.
- I don't even know if this printer can be reset, as some models are not that flexible.
- There isn't much information about the model... but there are lots of questions and not worthy of trust claims (*"this work, but first pay for the license etc..."*), so I have no confirmation of such mentions being legit or actually working.

Some Canon printers can be reset and both counters brought back to zero, I've done this many times with diff Canon printers, **but no luck with the IX6810. Can't find the specific series of button presses and the specific software**. Searching the web provided me lots of "results" but when testing... it didn't work.

I love this printer. It has some issue (a common Canon printing issue producing distorted black PGBK prints) but there is a workaround, not a fix). Besides resetting the counters of the printer I would also like to test if that issue can be fixed on service mode. I have tried service tool ST 4905 (supposedly the one for this printer) with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, digging, and trying, I give up, it's impossible to reset this exact model of printer, while I could say "*so it seems*", I'm pretty sure it is impossible.

Found several articles, tutorials and posts on the web from techs and owners stating it's impossible, they couldn't do it. Also found testimonials from owners saying they tried ABCDE... etc tools and failed to work. Found info explaining if you use the wrong version of the reset tool, the board/memory becomes unusable or impossible to reset (some say impossible, others say unusable), in my case the printer works, it's still useful so the "unusable" thing is not what it happened to me as the printer still works.

Anyway after several years, lots of research and digging, still can't find a single printer owner of this exact model being able to do so, after all it seems a rare not so popular model.

So really, after really trying, I would like to honestly discourage anyone wanting to do the same, the amount of time needed is not worth it and still no results. It's not "I give up", it's my honest answer, something I would have loved to find time ago to save me from trying with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start the printer in the service mode.
   i. With the printer power turned off, while pressing the Resume/Cancel button, press and hold the ON button.
   (DO NOT release the buttons.)
   ii. When the Power LED lights in green, while holding the ON button, release the Resume/Cancel button. (DO
   NOT release the ON button.)
   iii. While holding the ON button, press the Resume/Cancel button 5 times, and release the ON button. (Each
   time the Resume/Cancel button is pressed, the Alarm and Power LEDs light alternately, Alarm in orange
   and Power in green.)
   iv. When the Power LED lights in green, the printer is ready for the service mode operation.
2. Start the Service Tool on the connected computer.
   i. When a button is clicked in the Service Tool dialog box, that function is performed. During operation of the
   selected function, all the Service Tool buttons are dimmed and inactive.
   ii. When the operation is completed, "A function was finished." is displayed, and another function can be
   selected.
   iii. If a non-supported function is selected, "Error!" is displayed. Click OK in the error message dialog
   box to exit the error.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @valdemarpr, sorry for the late reply. Tried this procedure with no luck. Tried diff combinations of button-pressing, also with no luck. On two diff occasions (don't remember how many push-releases, perhaps 6 and 10) the computer detected a new printer (just like when in service mode, but it didn't say "service". Anyway the software tool didn't detect the printer. After a lot of research, I still don't find a single person on the web who managed to get this working, but I did find some people saying this model doesn't allow resetting. I don't know, still looking for solutions.

Comment: si utilizaste una version incorrecta de ST incompatible con esta m{aquina es probable que la eeprom haya quedado inutilizable porque ejecuta un comando sin respuesta y esto hace que el modo servicio quede inutilizable.

Comment: Gracias valdemarpr, eso leí en un par de lugares en la web. Encontré que si es la versión incorrecta queda IRRESETEABLE, porque por lo menos funcional sigue, funciona perfecto la printer, simplemente no funciona ningún reseteador. Por otro lado llevo mucho tiempo investigando y no he encontrado a ninguna persona que tenga el mismo exacto modelo y lo haya logrado, ubiqué notas que dicen que este modelo no se puede. Gracias.